# Retrieving Angular Fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm new in Agngular Firebase, I'm trying to write a ToDoList example, the task will be on , and depending on it's "status", I want to change  color.

controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('DemoApp', ['firebase']);
myApp.constant("FIREBASE_URL", "https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/todo/" )

function DemoCtrl($scope, $firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {

    // Get Stored TODOs
    var todosRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
$scope.todos = $firebase(todosRef);

 console.log($scope.todos);
 if($scope.todos.item == 'pending'){
    $scope.color = "#FFD5FF";
}else if($scope.todos.item == 'completed'){
    $scope.color = "#E1FFE1";


}   

}
```

Here is my html file, where I list tasks on

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js">   </script>


 <script src="controller.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl" class="container"  ng-app="DemoApp">
<h2>TASK LIST</h2>
<div ng-repeat="item in todos">
<div ng-style="{'width':'200px','padding':'20px','float':'left','border':'2px solid  #FFF','background-color':color}">  

    <!--COMPLETED ICON-->
   <span style="background:#FFD5FF;padding:10px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-   down" ng-if="item.estatus=='pending'" > </span> 
   <span style="background:#E1FFE1;padding:10px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"  ng-if="item.estatus=='completed'" > </span> 
    <small  class="text-warning"> [ {{item.id}} ]</small>
    <span>{{item.name}} </span><br>
    <span>[ {{item.status}} ]</span>

   </div>
   </div>
```

So I'm trying to change the ng-style background-color with {color} scope.

Any idea please this is not working?

```
if($scope.todos.item == 'pending'){
    $scope.color = "#FFD5FF";
}else if($scope.todos.item == 'completed'){
    $scope.color = "#E1FFE1";
}
```

Comment: are you getting errors on the browser dev console?

Comment: No erros, just this : Object {$bind: function, $add: function, $save: function, $set: function, $remove: function…}

Comment: and this is the object structure : 1407804228700: Object
1407804233395: Object
1407862760468: Object
1407866433994: Object
estatus: "pending"
id: 1407866433994
nombre: "Veronica Galindo"
__proto__: Object
1407875096632: Object

Comment: If your `todos` is an array-like structure, you should "cast" it to that using `todos.$asArray()`. This was a recent addition to AngularFire, so existing tutorials may not cover it yet. See this page for the official documentation on it: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-asarray

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip, I was working with and old version of firebase, and this documentation help me  a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above has several problems, the first of which is that `$scope.todos` should an *array*, so the reference of `$scope.todos.item` doesn't make sense.  At the very least, you'll need to index the array to get one item (e.g., `$scope.todos[0].name`).

Next, the *status* test is using the wrong attribute.  The conditional should probably be written something like this:

```
item = $scope.todos[0];
if (item.status == 'pending') {
  item.color = '#FFD5FF';
} else if (item.status == 'completed') {
  item.color = '#E1FFE1';
}
```

Below is a link to a brief but good tutorial on angularJS, Chapter 4 of which shows you how to use Firebase:

http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/

Comment: That link leads to "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."